# What is an Integration Point?

Tags: debugging

How is an **Integration Point** defined within the context of an application?

I've heard about it in a programming course but couldn't grasp the concept in a way that I could distinguish an integration point among other parts of the software.
The teacher in the course asked to make sure that software is responsive and stays stable when it comes to the operation in an integration point.

Sample integration points from the course:

1. When Software receives a user input
2. When Software makes an API call
   to a remote server.

Comment: the problem is that often people make up their own terms to mean "that specific thing which I am talking about." This is especially the case with the great divide between academic and industry programmers. So what the instructor meant could be nearly anything and we can only guess at that meaning - especially with a second hand account. The key to asking the question is not so much 'what id they mean' but rather 'I am trying to do this' type questions that don't rely upon someone's interpretation of a term heard from someone else.

Comment: @MichaelT Michael I am sure enough that "Integration Point" is not  "made up" by the instructor and even if it was, it would still make sense to ask my question here. I've done my researches before asking and I think programmers who deal with this term in their daily life are able to help with an answer and those who haven't heard about it may just ignore it. BTW, [rwong](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/620/rwong) has left a very helpful answer to my question before even I make an edit on it.

Comment: @YAAK: your instructor may have a broader definition of "Integration Point" than what I described in my answer. In particular, two pieces of software, running on separate machines, may be "piped" or "channeled" together over the network, and perform some synergistic operation useful to the person who concoct this configuration. Each software didn't know the other software's existence - each only consumes input data and produce output data. But it can be argued that this is also a kind of "Integration Point", at the system level. (System level = lots of parts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL; DR:**

Please review [all of the articles listed](http://www.objectmentor.com/omSolutions/oops_what.html) under "Object-Oriented Design" on  ObjectMentor.

---

*The following is my personal opinion, provided for a discussion. It should not be treated as a definition. There may be errors in this personal opinion.*

Integration point:

- Any abstract "facility" <sup>1</sup>, by design <sup>2</sup>, where the behavior of the application might be modified in a way that cause newly written / customer-written code (code that is not originally shipped as part of the application) to be executed.
- <sup>1</sup> These facilities may include, but not limited to: callback functions (or any first-class function objects), dependency injection points, OOP interfaces defined by the applications that can be concretely implemented by client software, OOP inheritable base classes provided by the application.
- <sup>2</sup> A proper integration point is one which is intended <sup>3</sup> by the "owners" (designers or vendors) of the application.

  - Typical software may have some facilities which allow execution of new code, but which are not intended by the owners of the application.
  - In security, this is almost certainly a software defect, and potentially a vulnerability which allows a malicious person to subvert the security system or the original purposes of the application. This is why unintended ones would not be normally considered an integration point.
- <sup>3</sup> Because very little constraints can be placed on the customer-written code being invoked from an integration point, the "owners" of the application cannot make unilateral guarantees of correct operations *unless* the customer-written code is designed carefully to avoid interfering the correctness of the application.

  - Thus, some expectation of responsibility and diligence is placed on the customer who write code to be executed from the integration point.

Comment: Your answer is helping a lot to understand this concept and perfectly makes sense.

Comment: Don't forget things like dll's, jars and certain libraries like slf4j.

Comment: My answer is definitely **too narrow**. At the time I wrote the answer, part of that came from an infosec training (intro level), where much of focus was on the "unwanted" kind of injecting code. Basically all the crazy wonderful ways to subvert a system.

Answer (score -3):

I encountered the term while at work which my boss eventually explained was he wanted me to get APIs from a fleet software supplier to integrate their software with our website for back-end use.
So, in my opinion, it's a way of merging a foreign software/ application to an existing application by any meaning of software possible.

Comment: This is an anecdote and an opinion, so I'd say `[citation needed]`.